# How can I prevent requirejs from pulling in another AMD module being loaded on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm using requirejs in an environment where I don't control all the code. This allows me to use my own version of jQuery without worrying about collisions with the other team's code. However, the other development group started using jquery.ui.widget.js which has this AMD code at the top:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define(["jquery"], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(jQuery);
    }
```

My requirejs define method is being called by this line,

```
define(["jquery"], factory);
```

which pulls their jQuery widget into my private jQuery. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Require.js has for this situation special setting - map

```js
require.config({
  // Add this map config in addition to any baseUrl or
  // paths config you may already have in the project.
  map: {
    // '*' means all modules will get 'jquery-private'
    // for their 'jquery' dependency.
    '*': {
      'jquery': 'jquery-private'
    },

    // 'your_module' wants a different jQuery module
    'your_module': {
      'jquery': 'your_jquery'
    }
  }
});

// and the 'your_module' module, in the
// your_module.js file:
define(['jquery'], function(jq) {
  // code
});
```

More information in [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm not understanding how this can help in my case.

Comment: in jquery.ui.widget.js requires "public" jquery module. Try to map "public" jquery module for using in jquery.ui.widget module. And your jquery module still clear of other plugins